# Bootstrap 4 grid not honoring col-* in column direction

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I have a bootstrap 4.1 app.  I'm trying to layout a set of 6 cards.

On a wide (landscape) display I want to display 2 rows of 3 columns.

```
[1] [2] [3]
[4] [5] [6]
```

But on a narrow (portrait) display, I want to display 3 rows of 2 columns and I want the cards to maintain order going down the column, like this:

```
[1] [4]
[2] [5]
[3] [6]
```

The problem I'm having is that it doesn't seem to honor the col-* when the grid is in column direction and I get this:

```
[1]
[2]
[3]
[4]
[5]
[6]
```

Here's my markup:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row flex-column flex-md-row">
        <div class="card col-6 col-md-4">
            <h5 class="card-header">Card 1</h5>
            <div class="card-body"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="card col-6 col-md-4">
            <h5 class="card-header">Card 2</h5>
            <div class="card-body"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="card col-6 col-md-4">
            <h5 class="card-header">Card 3</h5>
            <div class="card-body"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="card col-6 col-md-4">
            <h5 class="card-header">Card 4</h5>
            <div class="card-body"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="card col-6 col-md-4">
            <h5 class="card-header">Card 5</h5>
            <div class="card-body"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="card col-6 col-md-4">
            <h5 class="card-header">Card 6</h5>
            <div class="card-body"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

On the div with the row class I'm defaulting to flex-column to get the columnar direction at narrow widths.  I switch to row direction at medium size.  That seems to work.  On each card div I default to col-6 to get only two columns at small widths and switch to col-4 at medium size to get 3 columns with wider displays.

With wider displays, the grid honors the number of columns.  At narrow widths, nothing forces the cards to a second column.  What's the best way to handle that?

Comment: remove the `flex-column` class for smaller widths, that should display everything as intended, and then to reorder your cards in the way you need, you can define a `order-*` class on your columns

Comment: Either that or set a explicit height on your row, as setting `flex-column` will keep expanding the row indefinitely since the viewport can grow with it: https://codepen.io/IvanS95/pen/aQjBdz

Comment: also reasonably sure that `row` is by default set to row for display purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two approaches to solve this:

**First One: Ordering Columns**

You could remove the `flex-column` class from the row to keep the default behavior of the columns, then you can just reorder each column with the `order-*` classes to set them up in any position you want on the row.

[Bootstrap Docs for Ordering Classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/#order-classes)

**Second Option: Setting a max-height on the `row`**

Since `rows` are `flex containers`, they span the entire width of the page if available or otherwise defined, when you set `flex-column` you basically rotate the row, and since the viewport will keep growing with the page, you should set a `max-height` on the `row` so it knows when to wrap its `flex-items` (columns in this case) to a new column.

```css
.no-order {
   max-height: 300px
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
   <h1>Without Ordering</h1>
    <div class="row no-order flex-column flex-md-row">
        <div class="card col-6 col-md-4">
            <h5 class="card-header">Card 1</h5>
            <div class="card-body"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="card col-6 col-md-4">
            <h5 class="card-header">Card 2</h5>
            <div class="card-body"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="card col-6 col-md-4">
            <h5 class="card-header">Card 3</h5>
            <div class="card-body"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="card col-6 col-md-4">
            <h5 class="card-header">Card 4</h5>
            <div class="card-body"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="card col-6 col-md-4">
            <h5 class="card-header">Card 5</h5>
            <div class="card-body"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="card col-6 col-md-4">
            <h5 class="card-header">Card 6</h5>
            <div class="card-body"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- With Ordering -->
<div class="container mt-5">
   <h1>With Column Ordering</h1>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="card col-6 col-md-4 order-1 order-md-1">
            <h5 class="card-header">Card 1</h5>
            <div class="card-body"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="card col-6 col-md-4 order-3 order-md-2">
            <h5 class="card-header">Card 2</h5>
            <div class="card-body"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="card col-6 col-md-4 order-5 order-md-3">
            <h5 class="card-header">Card 3</h5>
            <div class="card-body"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="card col-6 col-md-4 order-2 order-md-4">
            <h5 class="card-header">Card 4</h5>
            <div class="card-body"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="card col-6 col-md-4 order-4 order-md-5">
            <h5 class="card-header">Card 5</h5>
            <div class="card-body"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="card col-6 col-md-4 order-6 order-md-6">
            <h5 class="card-header">Card 6</h5>
            <div class="card-body"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Working example: https://codepen.io/IvanS95/pen/aQjBdz

Comment: I can't get the first approach to work.  Removing the flex-column class from the row div and adding order-* to my card divs still didn't cause the cards to wrap to the next column.  The second approach does work.  Any idea why the first might not be working?

Comment: Hmm, I'd say maybe there was a typo, I updated my codepen to show what I meant, take a look, maybe there's something different on your code, let me know!

Comment: @JoeRattz Were you able to make it work? Maybe I missed something, just checking out

Comment: Yes, I was able to make it work,  Thank you!  I was missing that you were changing the order value for the different breakpoints.  The codepen helped a lot.  I now have that approach working.  I'm not sure which approach I like better though.  I prefer the natural flow of the items instead of hard-coding the order of each card at different breakpoints although having order control is nice.  Thanks!